# $tooltipProvider error at angular 1.4.7+

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bower, flot.tooltip

I am trying to upgrade my angular version from 1.3.15 to 1.4.7+. All my bower components got downloaded and gulp run successfully. When I load my page, I got the $tooltipProvider error in console.
[image: how to clear this]

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of components in the module "itranscript" needs a service named `$tooltip` (or on its provider `$tooltipProvider`), and the module defining that service is not available.

$tooltip is not a standard angular service. It probably is a service from an old version of angular ui bootstrap. And you probably forgot to depend on ui-bootstrap, or you depend on a newer version that no longer has this service, now renamed to `$uibTooltip`.

I don't see how you could get that error by just upgrading the angular version. You probably upgraded other libraries too.

Comment: Thanks. That's great. I upgraded anuglar-bootstrap to 1.3.1 from 0.12.1. Now I reverted that back and it got cleared. Is $tooltip renamed as $uibTooltip in the latest version?

Comment: All the services and directives were prefixed with `$uib`, yes.